# Chrome devtools: How to change the touch emulation pointer shadow color

Tags: mouse, colors, web-development, google-chrome-devtools

The devtools in Chrome/Chromium provide a device emulation for hand-held devices with touch screens. In this mode, the mouse pointer changes into a circular "shadow" to emulate a finger tip.

The color of this pointer is black, which is obviously not visible on a black background. This way, it is easy to loose track...

**Question:** Is there a way to change the color of the pointer, so that it is visible on a black background? Preferably, it should have an appearance that is visible on any background.

I've searched via Google, on Stack Overflow and Super User, but did not find any reference to changing the appearance of the color.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably satisfy

1. Open the mouse control panel.
2. Select the Pointer Options tab in the Mouse Properties window.
3. Then enable Display pointer trails option.
4. In case you don't like or are getting annoyed, like me, due to the
   trailer. Move the slider to the Short position and the trailer
   becomes very short.

Comment: Nice, might just work. However, my window manager does not let me create mouse trails. I've only seen that on MS Windows, so I guess you're on that platform. Perhaps I should have mentioned my platform (KDE at time of asking, LXCD currently, both on Linux), but I was thinking in the direction of some setting in Chromium itself. Anyway, I cannot test this.

Comment: I'm usually using Firefox and hadn't opened the devtools in Chromium some time. Actually, they have changed the cursor!!! It is now, low and behold, the same black circular shadow, but now extended with a light border! Very useful!